# For-in with window object

Tags: javascript, arrays, window, for-in-loop

The next code must return array of objects name with custom property. But it doesnt work and i dont know why.

```
    var test = {
    pr: true
}

alert(getObjName('pr'))

function getObjName(key) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var obj in window) {
        if (window[obj][key]) arr.push(obj)
    }
    return arr
}
```

Comment: Your code doens't make sense. Please add comments and clarify what you're asking

Comment: Why would the object's name be returned when accessing it by [key] subscript?  Wouldn't it be the object's value that's returned?  (caveat: I'm not a JS dev).

Comment: I have some objects in global spacename. I need to get array of names of these objects with custom properties. window[obj][key] checks is the object with property (key) exist. I tried window[obj].hasOwnProperty(key) but wih same result.